# Lambda Expression getting all data from object

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a user task join table - with ria services i go and get the usertaskjoin based on the userId.

```
UserTaskQueueJoin = new ObservableCollection<UserTaskQueueJoin>( _context.UserTaskQueueJoins);
```

once i get this UserTaskJoin object I want to then get the tasks from a query im running.

```
_query = _query.Where(x => UserTaskQueueJoin.Any(t => t.UserTaskQueueJoinID == x.AssignedToTaskQueueID));
```

UserTaskQueueJoin - UserTaskQueueJoinID, UserID, TaskQueueID

TaskQueue - TaskQueueID, InstitutionId, TaskQueueName

Task - TaskID, TaskQueueID, TaskName

What I ultimately am doing is running a query on the task table to only return items that are within a taskqueue. my first code snippet above gets the taskqueues a user is in..

The query call above is clearly not working.  I have tried with a .SelectMany and cannot get that to work.

Comment: I'm not clear on your object structure. Your user object has a TaskID and your task object has a TaskID? I would think your task object should have a UserID to establish that one to many relationship. (one user has many tasks)?

Comment: So essentially you have a `Users` object and a `Tasks` object and you want to join them together based on the ID of the task, right?

Comment: You know, an outline of the User and Task classes might help.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question and it quite a bit more clear..hopefully?

Comment: I use this query and send it back to my domain service. I have a variety of check that i append to this query. dates, is active, assigned to me...after i create this long query i then send it back to my ria service call and it executes.

Comment: Still not entirely clear on the object model, but this part sticks out to me: "t => t.UserTaskQueueJoinID == x.AssignedToTaskQueueID". If this is a join table, is UserTaskQueueJoinId a surrogate key? Because that would probably *not* be the same as the task queue id you're looking for. (In other words, we'd need to see the actual definitions of these tables to see if the fields are correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your model contains all the appropriate FK-type relationships, it might be as simple as :

```
_query = _query.SelectMany(x => x.UserTaskQueueJoins.TaskQueues.Tasks);
```

or even

```
_query = _query.SelectMany(x => x.TaskQueues.Tasks);
```